# Change Webkit properties through Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

Please help me, Might be cause I'm fairly new to CSS Animations and Javascript but I am using a code that is suppose to change the properties of it and when I run the code it does everything else with in the code except for change the properties in CSS of the desired div. I've tried all four of these and none of them seem to work, are they out of date? Is there a new way of doing this or what? None of them work at all.

```
document.getElementById('playBar').style.webkitAnimationDuration = 20 + "s";
document.getElementById('playBar').style.animationDuration = 20 + "s";
document.getElementById('playBar').style['-webkit-transition-duration'] = '50s';

value = Math.floor((100 / duration) * currentTime);
document.getElementById('playBar').setAttribute("style","-webkit-filter:grayscale(" + value + "%)")
```

CSS CODE

```
#playBar {
width: 1px;
height: 12px;
background: white;
float:left;
-webkit-animation: mymove infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-webkit-animation-duration: 10s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
animation: mymove infinite;
animation-duration: 0s;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-webkit-keyframes mymove {
from {width: 0%;}
to {width: 100%;}
}

@keyframes mymove {
from {width: 0%;}
to {width: 100%;}
}
```

Comment: Try `WebkitAnimationDuration`, usually all letters following a `-` character (removed in JavaScript) should be uppercased. Although note that `animation-duration` and `transition-duration` are two different properties.

Comment: @DavidThomas 
So which one do I use the first one right? Just correct the wording?

Comment: It depends whether you're using a CSS animation (using a named `@keyframes` animation), or a transition.

Comment: @DavidThomas
I added the CSS Code so you can see exactly what I'm doing. I'm basically trying to make a loading bar. But I can't control the animation in Javascript.

Comment: @DavidThomas
To be more clear I want the code to look like this, however this obviously will not work.                        

document.getElementById('playBar').style.-webkit-animation-duration = 20 + "s";

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
this.style['-webkit-transition-duration'] = '50s'
```

use

```
this.style.WebkitTransitionDuration="50s"
```